# How to use correct pointer in this linked list

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, queue, function-definition

This is a code I get from codesdope.com and I modified a little bit to understand how Queue ADT with linked list works.

However, I get stuck using pointer on this codes.
I simply tried to print out all elements in queue, trying to change parameter.
And I cannot go to next node from the queue, am I trying something not possible from this code?
because it is desinged like this or any solution here?

I need your help or tips how to use proper pointer for following pointer.

'''

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
#define FULL 10


typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} NodeT;


typedef struct QueueRep{
    int length;
    NodeT *head;
    NodeT *tail;
} QueueRep;

typedef struct QueueRep *queue;


void initialize(queue q){
    q->length = 0;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->tail = NULL;
}


int isempty(queue q) {
    return(q->tail == NULL);
}

void enqueue(QueueRep *q, int value) {
    if(q->length < FULL) {
        NodeT *tmp;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
        tmp->data = value;
        tmp->next = NULL;
        if(!isempty(q)) {
            q->tail->next = tmp;
            q->tail = tmp;
        } else {
            q->head = q->tail = tmp;
        } 
        q->length++;
    } else {
        printf("List is full\n");
    }
}

int dequeue(QueueRep *q) {
    NodeT *tmp;
    int n = q->head->data;
    tmp = q->head;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    q->length--;
    free(tmp);
    return(n);
}

/* original display function
void display(NodeT *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d\n", head -> data);
        display(head->next);
    }
}
*/

/* I would like to print like this !!!! */
void display(queue q) {
    NodeT *p = q->head;
    if(p->data == NULL) {
        printf("NULL\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        display(q->head); //wrong pointer? how can your fix here?
        
    }
    
}



int main() {
    QueueRep *q;
    q = malloc(sizeof(QueueRep));
    initialize(q);
    enqueue(q,10);
    enqueue(q,20);
    enqueue(q,30);
    printf("Queue before dequeue\n");
    //display(q->head); 
    display(q); //this is What I am trying to use
    dequeue(q);
    printf("\nQueue after dequeue\n");
    //display(q->head);
    display(q); //this is What I am trying to use
    return 0;
}
```

'''

Comment: This is just a bad code. What is the problem?

Comment: The data member is not a pointer. So this if statement if(p->data == NULL) { does not make a sense.

Comment: In this recursive call  display(q->head); the argument has a different type than the function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This function definition

```
/* I would like to print like this !!!! */
void display(queue q) {
    NodeT *p = q->head;
    if(p->data == NULL) {
        printf("NULL\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
        display(q->head); //wrong pointer? how can your fix here?
    }
}
```

is wrong and shall not compile.

For example the data member `data` of the structure `node`  is not a pointer. So this if statement

```
    if(p->data == NULL) {
```

is invalid because there are compared an object of the type `int` (`p->data`) with null pointer `NULL`.

In this statement

```
display(q->head); //wrong pointer? how can your fix here?
```

the function is called with the argument of the type `struct node` while the corresponding function parameter has the type `queue`. So again the compiler will issue an error for this statement.

You could split the function into two functions. For example

```
void display_list( const NodeT *head )
{
    if ( !head )
    {
        puts( "NULL" );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "%d ", head->data );
        display_list( head->next );
    }
}
```

and

```
void display( const QueueRep *q ) 
{
    display_list( q->head );
}
```

The function `dequeue`

```
int dequeue(QueueRep *q) {
    NodeT *tmp;
    int n = q->head->data;
    tmp = q->head;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    q->length--;
    free(tmp);
    return(n);
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior. Firstly it does not check whether the queue is empty/. Secondly it does not set the pointer `tail` to `NULL` when a single node in the queue is being deleted.

The function could be defined for example the following way

```
int dequeue( QueueRep *q, int *data ) 
{
    int success = q->head != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        NodeT *tmp = q->head;
        *data = tmp->data;

        q->head = q->head->next;
        if ( !q->head ) q->tail = NULL;
        --q->length;
 
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

Pay attention to that in main there is no great sense to declare an object of the type `QueueRep` dynamically. You could write

```
QueueRep q;
initialize( &q );
```

And this typedef

```
typedef struct QueueRep *queue;
```

only confuses readers of the code. In some places of the program you are using the type `QueueRep *` while in other places you are using the type `queue`.

Comment: Thank you so much Vlad! 
огромное спасибо